# How to make wider arrows in combobox and updown controls in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

When I set larger font, arrows start to grow vertically. How can I stretch them also horizontally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system draws both of these controls. You really ought to let the system decide how to draw them.

If you don't want to do that then you'll have to override the `Paint` method and draw the controls yourself. Be warned that this is non-trivial once you factor in all the possible themes that you app may encounter (Windows Classic, Windows Basic, Aero).  Or you could look for a 3rd party component that has already done this.

Comment: I agree with the combo arrow - which reflects `iScrollWidth` of `NONCLIENTMETRICS` (or `SM_CXVSCROLL` of `GetSystemMetrics`). But the other one has a width property (initially set to the same though)..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is relevant in your case and guess the answer will be downvoted for that, but did you thought of using the ScalyBy / ChangeScale of the Form/Control?

Comment: The combo box sets its height automatically so the the font fits